# Cannot Download file by HttpClient or WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, http, dotnet-httpclient

Hi everyone and thanks for your attention. I have written an action that returns FileStreamResult or NotModified status code and it works in Postman but if I use C# code it doesn't work.

```cs
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(Guid id, [FromServices] IContentTypeProvider contentTypeProvider)
        {
            string? hash = Request.Headers.IfNoneMatch;
            long userId = long.Parse(User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
            FileDto fileDto = await _fileService.GetMetadataAsync(id, userId);
            if (fileDto.Hash == hash)
            {
                return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.NotModified);
            }

            Stream stream = await _fileService.GetStreamAsync(id, userId);
            string? contentType;
            if (contentTypeProvider.TryGetContentType(fileDto.Name, out contentType) is not true)
            {
                contentType = "application/octet-stream";
            }

            Response.Headers.CacheControl = "public";
            Response.Headers.ETag = fileDto.Hash;
            return new FileStreamResult(stream, contentType)
            {
                FileDownloadName = fileDto.Name,
            };
        }
```

**The postman's result:**
[image]

The behavior of HttpClient (and WebClient) is very strange:

1. Return 200 status code but content is empty

[image]
2. Etag is null but if serialize the response as JSON it shows that Etag exists in response headers.

[image]

**Serilized Response:**

```json
{
    "Version": "1.1",
    "Content": {
        "Headers": [
            {
                "Key": "Content-Length",
                "Value": [
                    "0"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Key": "Content-Type",
                "Value": [
                    "image/jpeg"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Key": "Content-Disposition",
                "Value": [
                    "attachment; filename=shrek.jpg; filename*=UTF-8\u0027\u0027shrek.jpg"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "ReasonPhrase": "OK",
    "Headers": [
        {
            "Key": "Date",
            "Value": [
                "Fri, 21 Apr 2023 11:36:24 GMT"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Key": "Server",
            "Value": [
                "Kestrel"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Key": "Cache-Control",
            "Value": [
                "public"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Key": "ETag",
            "Value": [
                "DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "TrailingHeaders": [],
    "RequestMessage": {
        "Version": "1.1",
        "VersionPolicy": 0,
        "Content": null,
        "Method": {
            "Method": "GET"
        },
        "RequestUri": "https://localhost:201/api/files/ad71424e-3ac1-47cd-b36d-107deadce4f2",
        "Headers": [
            {
                "Key": "Authorization",
                "Value": [
                    "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoic2Vjb25kVXNlckRvd25sb2FkRmlsZUB3aXRoQWNjZXNzRmlsZS50ZXN0Iiwic3ViIjoiMiIsImp0aSI6ImRhZDUxMTNlLWFiOWYtNDRlMS1iMTI2LTE0OWZjYzRhNDk2OCIsImh0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20vd3MvMjAwOC8wNi9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvcm9sZSI6IkVtYWlsIENvbmZpcm1lZCIsImV4cCI6MTY4MjA3Nzg4NSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6MjAxIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6MjAxIn0.MBiMYbOuZkEkwJKySNTBqczPPjEQfGyVi_G1jPw6vnk"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Properties": {},
        "Options": {}
    },
    "IsSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

Why Postman works but HttpClient (WebClient too) does not? Maybe I missed something?

Comment: For the etag the specs define that you have to putt double quotes around the value. Not having those might cause your issue. For the stream the cursor might be set to the end so you'll have to set it to `myStream.Position = 0` before copying it to your array.

Comment: Since you have one client that works and another that doesn't, run a proxy like Fiddler to capture both requests and compare them.